# Trap all http request in android by creating a service?

Tags: android

I am working on an android app in which I want all http request sent by android phone .Is it possible in android by creating a service?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a service to do so, but it will make your code much more difficult, because services have different lifecycles than activities and fragments, they can exist even if the UI is not running. I give you the advice to handle it in your application code. One good library is [`OkHttp`](https://github.com/square/okhttp) or if you want something more abstract you can go with [`Retrofit`](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

Comment: With retrofit you have a class called `Interceptor` which allows you to trap all the requests. Look at the documentation before putting a -1

Comment: I want to trap all the request whether it is not from my app .Means i want to create an app which trap all other request(not from my app)

Comment: This is not possible unless you are root. Android does not provide this API for security, imagine you can scrap all the requests that happens from your device, you could break all the apps modifying them.

Comment: Is there any way to only  log the request .NOT TO MODIFY

Comment: You can't even access, nor modify this requests, unless you are root and still it wouldn't be easy. Accessing all requests will be a fine grained operation on de network module because you can't access to operations on other applications or processes unless the allow you to, which is not the case